# the fine print - Does it mean "the thin print" or "the delicate print"?

Tags: word-usage

Does "print" here mean "thin" or "delicate (good quality)"?

> Donald Trump and his family have spent the last four years making the airtight case that they view the presidency as simply a means to enrich themselves and their associates. They probably don’t particularly like that reputation and, yet, it hasn’t stopped them from funneling taxpayer money to their private business, gouging the Secret Service, and raising legal defense funds that **the fine print** says could go directly to their pockets. Oh, and, according to a new report, setting up a shell company that spent hundreds of millions of campaign dollars to pay Trump family members along with other expenditures it seemingly wanted to keep under wraps.

Source: [Jared Kushner Reportedly Created a Shell Company to Secretly Pay Trump Family Members and Spend Half the Campaign’s Cash](https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2020/12/jared-kushner-campaign-shell-company)

Comment: Note that *"the **small print**"* in such contexts is essentially ***metaphorical***. Nobody really knows or cares whether the (potentially unfavourable to the client) detailed conditions are written in a smaller font size in any given case. All that matters is ***it's a lot of words*** that hardly anyone ever reads before signing a contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means [small print](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/small-print) - detail in a legal document that not everyone takes the trouble to read.

Comment: Brits say 'small print' in situations where Americans say 'fine print'.

Comment: Yeah, I've never heard "small print" before - it's always "fine print" in North America.

Comment: As my link indicates.